# Index on expression (JSON_EXTRACT) not used

Tags: sqlite, database-indexes

I'm having trouble getting SQLite to index an expression.  Specifically, I want to create an index on a particular property in a JSON object.

```
CREATE TABLE test (tags JSON);
INSERT INTO test VALUES(JSON_OBJECT('someKey', 'someValue'));

CREATE INDEX test_idx ON test(JSON_EXTRACT(tags, '$.someKey'));
EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(tags, '$.someKey') FROM test;
```

This query plan says:

> SCAN TABLE test

What I'm expecting is some sort of `SEARCH TABLE test USING INDEX...`.

Any thoughts on how I can correct this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It turns out that the index isn't used if I attempt to `SELECT` it.

I have to use the `JSON_EXTRACT()` expression in a `WHERE` or `ORDER BY` clause.  If I do that, it works fine.

```
EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN SELECT * FROM test WHERE JSON_EXTRACT(tags, '$.someKey')="asdf";
```

> SEARCH TABLE test USING INDEX test_idx (=?)

Answer (score 2):

Index makes a balanced tree and is intended for locating and sorting. An expression doesn't need to locate or sort unless in WHERE or ORDER BY subclause

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, @Zim.  In my specific use case, I was using it in a WHERE clause, but I was testing by just having the expression in SELECT, which wasn't working, and I hadn't understood why.